# Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' error when trying to update mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python to call a table in mysql and executing queries. I am getting an error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

tbl_1 is a table in which I have to update isprocessed column.

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE tbl_1 SET isprocessed=1 where name='+body)
cursor.close()
cursor1 = db.cursor()
cursor1.execute('SELECT name,height,age,weight from tbl_1 where name='+body)
```

Body is taking value in a message queue.If I run the code without UPDATE query its running fine. I thought `cursor.close` will solve the problem but it didn't. I also restarted mysql. I have gone through similar questions but none of them solve my issue.Any help appreciated.

I have set `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` from 50 to 63000

Comment: wild guess: `cursor.commit()` instead of `cursor.close()`

Comment: COMMIT would help, but does not explain it. Are both cursors created from the same connection object? Your isolation level is set to SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: @geertjanvdk yes both cursors created from same connection object.isolation level is SERIALIZABLE

Comment: @sau: If both cursors are from the same connection object, there should be no problem. At least, I can not reproduce anything. There is something in the equation that is still missing. MySQL version maybe? What version of MySQLdb? I guess auto commit is off? Post complete, small application showing the problem, possible?

Comment: @isedev I am using django and getting the same error when I call save() method on a model

Comment: can you place a breakpoint before running SELECT and in database execute SHOW PROCESSLIST. Then we will see what is locking your table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem faced due to many reasons.

1. When you are running your program (or file) do not open MYSQL in another terminal. This could cause read-write conflicts.
2. If you are using django as well as MYSQL direct execution (with cursors) make sure you commit your transaction with the command: `{your_connection_object}.commit()`. Eg: `self.conn.commit()`

The commands to debug are as follows (Read More about them if you are new to them):

**INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT:**

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

**Process Currently Running:**

```
Show processlist;
```

**Kill a particular process:**

```
kill *process_id*;
```

**Currently running Transactions:**

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`innodb_trx` ORDER BY `trx_started`;
```